# How to filter array from resource

Tags: android, arrays, listview, filter

I am working on android app, Here i have to array resources in xml file and two listview in different activities first array list is of state in India while second is for districts of India. i am showing states in first listview and i want to show the district in second list view but my problem is i can not think for how to filter district based on selected state. for ex when user selects Chhattisgarh as state then the second listview should show only districts from Chhattisgarh not others.

Thank you in advance

Comment: i didn't try it. actually i can't think anything  how to perform it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define states as a single array list and different array lists for districts in values/arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="states">
        <item>state1</item>
        <item>state2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="state1-districts">
        <item>district1</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="state2-districts">
        <item>district1</item>
</string-array>
```

In code, you can access your states array:

```
activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.states);
```

And you can access districts of a specific state:

```
String districtResourceName = "state1-districts";
int districtId = getResources().getIdentifier(districtResourceName, "array", "com.your.project");
activity.getResources().getStringArray(districtId);
```

Comment: @Surya no problem, I'm glad I could help. I see today is your first day here, in StackOverflow. So, if you'd like, you could accept my answer and receive your first badge!

Comment: i got some error @ayorhan

  here is link for files 

[logcat]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwfKN-EDWU79ODhXMVQ0UDAzOEU/edit?usp=sharing

[array file] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwfKN-EDWU79dHJPZy1XamJJNWc/edit?usp=sharing

[stata array list]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwfKN-EDWU79Z3hqcUp1X3Y2STg/edit?usp=sharing

[menifest]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwfKN-EDWU79V1VjTlo2SDVEQlE/edit?usp=sharing

[java file] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwfKN-EDWU79NXZiTUJIZHdLMms/edit?usp=sharing

pls help

Comment: The error you get, "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x0", happens when a particular resource file you're looking for is not available. I believe you get this error when you get incorrect data from intent. Make sure, you have the correct resource name here: "String loksabhaResourseName = state +"_LOKSABHA";"